# Passing user id with AuthController

Tags: flutter, dart, aqueduct

I just made simple authentication app using aqueduct as a back end. I used codes from aqueduct documentation pages for login and registering. When I login with this code in backend

```
 router
    .route('/auth/token')
    .link(() => AuthController(authServer));
```

I get back token, token type and expiration date, Is there any chance to also pass userId? Or do I have to create my own controller to do that?

UPDATE
or how can I in my backend to save user id when saving the data

```
  @Operation.post()
  Future<Response> addData(@Bind.body(ignore: ['id']) Data newData) async {
    final query = Query<Data>(context)..values = newData;
    final insertData = await query.insert();
    return Response.ok(insertData);
  }
```

Comment: Why do you need to pass back the user id?

Comment: @Suragch honestly just to protect user data. As from aqueduct documentation we can protect the data with this code in backend `where((p) => p.author).identifiedBy(forUserID)` so I believe that when creating a data we have to also save user id with them.. therefore I thought to have the userId in frontend to save it together with the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Flutter frontend

Login initially with the username/email and password. You will get an authorization token back from the server if the username and password are valid. Then use that token to make further privileged requests to the server.

You don't need to save any personal data about the user (email or password) on the client. You can save the token, though, if you don't want to make the user log in again the next time they use the app. When saving the token you should use a secure storage option. The [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) plugin uses [KeyChain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services) on iOS and [KeyStore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore) on Android.

### Aqueduct backend

You can use the user IDs all you want on the backend. I don't know of any need to pass them to the client, though. On the backend you can query the user ID and then use it to fetch other information from the database.

Here is an example from the [documentation](https://aqueduct.io/docs/auth/authorizer/#authorization-objects):

```
class NewsFeedController extends ResourceController {
  NewsFeedController(this.context);

  ManagedContext context;

  @Operation.get()
  Future<Response> getNewsFeed() async {
    var forUserID = request.authorization.ownerID;

    var query = Query<Post>(context)
      ..where((p) => p.author).identifiedBy(forUserID);

    return Response.ok(await query.fetch());
  }
}
```

The client only passed in the token. Aqueduct looks up the user id for you based on that token. Now you know the user ID.

Your other tables can have a column for the user ID so that only that user may save and retrieve their data. In the example above, Posts have an Author and an Author has an ID, that is, the user ID.

```
where((p) => p.author).identifiedBy(forUserID)
```

is equivalent to

```
where((p) => p.author.id).equalTo(forUserID)
```

You can read about this in the [Advanced Queries](https://aqueduct.io/docs/db/advanced_queries/#filtering-results-of-a-fetch-operation) section of the documentation.

Comment: Oh I see.. Please help me to understand one more thing.. So if I send request from my frontend to save some data in the db table then how can I in my backend tell to save also user id to make the data private to that user? That wasn't really explain in that documentation that is why I'm bit confused

Comment: I've read that part about querying I just don't understand how to save it so we can query it.. look at my updated question. Or does it mean that the data table doesn't need any column with that information?

Comment: @delmin This looks like a new question. I prefer to answer just one question per answer. Can you create a new question? I'll look at it tomorrow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61526061/aqueduct-how-to-save-userid-in-my-backend