# Aqueduct - How to save client data without the user ID in my backend

Tags: dart, aqueduct

How can I save data for a user when I don't know their user ID? I want to save it in my Aqueduct back end so I can protect and query current user data?

```
@Operation.post()
Future<Response> addData(@Bind.body(ignore: ['id']) Data newData) async {
  final query = Query<Data>(context)..values = newData;
  final insertData = await query.insert();
  return Response.ok(insertData);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqueduct automatically generates a user ID when you create a new user. That id is associated with the user's login credentials or access token.

In your example here the user passed in some data in a Data model:

```
@Operation.post()
Future<Response> addData(@Bind.body(ignore: ['id']) Data newData) async {
  final query = Query<Data>(context)..values = newData;
  final insertData = await query.insert();
  return Response.ok(insertData);
}
```

The problem is that the user didn't know their own ID so that is missing in `newData`.

Assuming that you have the route [protected with an Authorizer](https://aqueduct.io/docs/auth/authorizer/), then you can get the user ID like this:

```
final userID = request.authorization.ownerID;
```

So you can use it like this:

```
@Operation.post()
Future<Response> addData(@Bind.body(ignore: ['id']) Data newData) async {

  final userID = request.authorization.ownerID;

  final query = Query<Data>(context)
    ..values.id = userId
    ..values.something = newData.something
    ..values.another = newData.another;

  final insertData = await query.insert();
  // if insert was successful then...
  return Response.ok(insertData);
}
```

By the way, since you are returning the inserted data to the user, it will include the userId with it. [The client shouldn't need that, though.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61524878/3681880)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.. It was really helpful and I really appreciate that.. I had problem from the beginning understand where the `request` statement is coming from therefore I did't think about getting the user id that way... Just for clarification can you explain where is the `request` statement coming from?

Comment: @delmin Your controller extends `ResourceController` and `request` is a member variable of that class.